# Powershell how to take string from file and put into a variable

Tags: string, powershell, select-string

I am writing a Powershell script to "build" Windows 7 PCs: adding users, printers, applications, changing settings, et al.  I am adding some printer drivers using PNPUtil, but the problem is I won't know what "Published name" the drivers will be given.

If I put the output from the PNPUtil command into a .txt file, is there a way for me to then take the ***_*_**.inf Published name and put it into a variable so that I can then use that name to add the printer using $printerclass.CreateInstance()?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a file if PNPUtil only outputs the name your interested in.  That is, you can assign its output to a variable like so:

```
$result = pnputil.exe
```

BTW if you want to use a file, to read content from a file you use Get-Content:

```
pnputil.exe > result.txt
$result = Get-Content result.txt
$line = $result | Foreach {if ($_ -match 'assigned an (\w+\.inf)') {$matches[1]}}
```

Comment: Thank you, Keith - getting closer.  Here is what the PNP add command outputs -

"Microsoft PnP Utility

Processing inf :            AW3N_64PPD.INF
Driver package added successfully.
Published name :            oem231.inf


Total attempted:              1
Number successfully imported: 1"


It will always be assigned an "oem000.inf" with the "000" being a number.  So I need to get that "oem___.inf" and put that into a variable.  Which was why I figured I could pipe the output into a .txt file and look for the "oem*.inf".

Comment: Sorry - the comments leave out the look of the file - there are a couple of blank lines in there.

Comment: Okay - I found my own solution: Once the .inf file is added, the driver names are stored in the Microsoft update files.  I just need to know the specific name of the driver I need from each .inf file in order to add the Printers.
............
However, I'd still love to know how to get a string from a line from a file using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I found my own solution: Once the .inf file is added, all the driver names in that .inf are stored in the Microsoft update files. I just need to know the specific name of the driver I need from each .inf file in order to add the Printers.

However, I'd still love to know how to get a string from a line from a file using Powershell.